# Add a custom message to a formly field after submit

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I have a formly form of which I do not know what validation errors I will receive in advance. So, my plan: submit the form to the server, get errors back if they exist, then add the error message to the field in question. My code is this:

```js
/* global angular */
(function() {

  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('formlyExample', [
    'formly',
    'formlyBootstrap',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngMessages'
  ]);

  app.run(function(formlyConfig, formlyValidationMessages) {
    formlyConfig.extras.errorExistsAndShouldBeVisibleExpression = 'fc.$touched || form.$submitted';
  });

  app.config(function(formlyConfigProvider) {

    formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper({
      name: 'validation',
      types: ['input'],
      templateUrl: 'error-messages.html'
    });

  });

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl(formlyVersion) {
    var vm = this;
    // funcation assignment
    vm.onSubmit = onSubmit;
    vm.env = {
      angularVersion: angular.version.full,
      formlyVersion: formlyVersion
    };

    vm.model = {};
    vm.options = {};

    vm.fields = [{
      key: 'coolValue',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        required: false,
        type: 'text',
        label: 'Cool Value'
      }
    }, ];

    vm.originalFields = angular.copy(vm.fields);

    // function definition
    function onSubmit() {
      //if (vm.form.$valid) {
      //    vm.options.updateInitialValue();
      //   alert(JSON.stringify(vm.model), null, 2);
      // }
    }
  });

})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px
}
.formly-field {
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}
.error-messages {
  position: relative;
}
.error-messages,
.message {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .3s linear all;
}
.message {
  font-size: .8em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: #a94442;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.error-messages.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.message.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
}
.error-messages.ng-enter,
.message.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  top: -10px;
}
.error-messages.ng-leave,
.message.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
}
.error-messages.ng-leave-active,
.message.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Twitter bootstrap -->
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- apiCheck is used by formly to validate its api -->
  <script src="//npmcdn.com/api-check@latest/dist/api-check.js"></script>
  <!-- This is the latest version of angular (at the time this template was created) -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>

  <!-- This is the latest version of formly core. -->
  <script src="//npmcdn.com/angular-formly@latest/dist/formly.js"></script>
  <!-- This is the latest version of formly bootstrap templates -->
  <script src="//npmcdn.com/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap@latest/dist/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap.js"></script>

  <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-angular-messages/v1.4.4/angular-messages.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-angular-animate/v1.4.4/angular-animate.js"></script>

  <title>Angular Formly Example</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="formlyExample" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <div>
    <form ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()" name="vm.form" novalidate>
      <formly-form model="vm.model" fields="vm.fields" options="vm.options" form="vm.form">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.options.resetModel()">Reset</button>
      </formly-form>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- Put custom templates here -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="error-messages.html">
    <formly-transclude></formly-transclude>
    <div ng-messages="fc.$error" ng-if="form.$submitted || options.formControl.$touched" class="error-messages">
      <div ng-message="{{ ::name }}" ng-repeat="(name, message) in ::options.validation.messages" class="message">{{ message(fc.$viewValue, fc.$modelValue, this)}}</div>
    </div>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And a JSBin page: http://jsbin.com/nupumakata/edit?html,js,output

What I'm trying to do: as soon as you hit the submit button, a custom validation message  should be added to the Cool Value field. Since I don't know beforehand what errors will appear, I can't configure messages beforehand. So this:

```
formlyValidationMessages.addTemplateOptionValueMessage('pattern', 'patternValidationMessage', '', '', 'Invalid Input');
```

Would not work. In the answer I'm looking for, the message is added from inside the Submit function and only shown after the submit button is pressed (no error is shown until the submit button is pressed). I can't find in the documentation for Formly how to do this. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Could you setup a plunkr with this?

Comment: I added a JSBin link to mess around in.

Comment: You just want to update the field with a custom message upon submit, correct?

Comment: Yes! From the submit method, just add whatever message you want to the input field, so it is handled in the same way a validation message would show up.

Comment: Okay, so this is a pathetic but probably working model of what you want.Please have a look at the functionality only.Have a look at the [link](http://jsbin.com/yesabibumi/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: The idea is correct. However, I'm looking to add the error to the input field, so the input gets a red border, and it looks more "natural", instead of just adding another DIV and putting a message there.

Comment: Nearing a solution, should have something  in 24 hours ish

Comment: Sweet, thanks for taking your time to help me!

Comment: Have you come across this [link](http://www.seangwright.me/blog/development/displaying-error-messages-on-submission-with-angular-formly/)?

Comment: Hi, please check the answer and let me know what you think of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I've done is I've gone ahead and given the field a custom template as follows:

```
 formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper({
      name: 'inputWrapper',
  template: '<div ng-class="to.changeColor==\'red\'? \'redBorder\' : \'otherBorder\'"><formly-transclude></formly-transclude>{{to.keyVal}}</div>'
    });
```

The form elements are defined through a schema format to allow each element to be individually accessed.

```
vm.schema={
    "schema": {
        "coolValue" : [{
                "key": "coolValue",
                "type": "input",

          "wrapper": ['inputWrapper'],
                "templateOptions": {
                   "type" : "text",
                  "label": 'Cool Value',
                  "keyVal":"",
                  "changeColor":"green"
                }

         }]


    }

};
```

Finally, the `onSubmit` function

```
function onSubmit() {

//Do whatever you want here
//Let's say your server returns an error "iNVALID Credentials"
   var response={
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization",
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials"
  }
};
vm.schema.schema.coolValue[0].templateOptions.changeColor="red";
      vm.schema.schema.coolValue[0].templateOptions.keyVal=response.error.message;

    }
  });
```

You can essentially pass any error message or response from the server here.

The CSS contains a class to add a red `border` to the field.You are free to disable this.Feel free to ping  if you need anything in this area as well.

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/hiyawiwudi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Thanks! I'll be back at work tomorrow, where my workstation is. I'll try to implement your solution, and if it works I'll accept the answer!

Comment: It took a little adjusting for my situation, but it works great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

here is my [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tumiwe/edit?html,js,output)

**NOTE** :

1. I haven't worked with angular-formly. So it might not be the most efficient solution. But it does what you are looking for.
2. I have made changes in your `error-template.html` and `vm.fields.templateOptions`
3. I have created a new field `vm.fields.tempalteOptions.customErrorMessage`. And I change the value of this field from `onSubmit()`.
4. for keeping the example simple, I am doing `vm.fields[0].templateOptions.customErrorMessage = "Custom error message from rest service";`. You can get the `field` by `vm.fields.key` rather than getting it by index i.e. `vm.fields[0]`
5. Also for keeping the answer simple and avoiding attention from unnecessary details I have marked `required:true` for this input, this was false in your case. So in your code you can write a custom validator using formly and then when rest service returns error for a particular field make this validator set the validation as invalid and then show the custom message. for [custom validator](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/advanced/validators)

Hope above solves your problem. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try to answer this! However, my problem still remains: I need the error to only show after the submit button is pressed, regardless of whether the field is required or not. The idea is that after a POST, the server will reply with a JSON object with validation errors. I want to insert these into the corresponding fields after the POST. This appears to just change the validation message of an error already detected before the POST.